# Linq statement has 10 errors

Tags: c#, linq

My Linq statement is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TourService_Someone
{
    class AuthenticateUser : IAuthenticateUser
    {
        string IAuthenticateUser.AuthenticateUser(User user)
        {
            AbcTourContext con = new AbcTourContext();

            User returnedUser = from u in con.Users
                                where u.username == user.username and u.password == user.password
                                select u;

            if (returnedUser == null)
            {
                return "Login Failed!";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Login Success!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Please note**, I am quite new to Linq.

---

It has the following errors:

1. `A query body must end with a select clause or a group by clause.` This error is shown on the `and` keyword in the statement.
2. `; Expected`. This error is shown on the `and` keyword in the statement.
3. `The type namespace "and" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. This error is shown on the `and` keyword in the statement.
4. `The range variable 'u' conflicts with a previous declaration of 'u'`. This error is shown on the `u` of its first occurrence.
5. `; Expected`. This error is shown in the u.password field.

---

6. `The name "password" does not exist in the current context`. This error is shown in the u.password field.
7. `; Expected`. This error is shown on the select keyword.
8. `The type namespace "select" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. This error is shown on the select keyword.
9. `A local variable or function named 'u' is already defined in this scope`. This error is shown on the last occurrence of 'u'.
10. `The variable 'u' is declared but never used`. This error is shown on the last occurrence of 'u'.

---

The variable `con` is Entity framework's DBContext and it's my context and from that, I am getting a DBSet. The user is passed as a parameter in a method that the Linq statement is in.

I have no clue why all these errors are happening. I have written Linq statements before, and they were fine. But, this is something else.

Am I overlooking something very simple???

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my User model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace TourService_Someone
{
    [Table("User")]
    public partial class User
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `User returnedUser = (from u in con.Users where u.username == user.username and u.password == user.password select u).First();`

Comment: @zaitsman No, the same errors are still there. In addition, it does not recognize the first method.

Comment: Ok so show us the `User` model

Comment: and make sure you have imported `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I am using `using System.Linq;` and I will update my question to include the User model.

Comment: Gross syntax mistakes often produce less-than-stellar error messages.  Statements belong *inside* a method.

Comment: Where exactly you have written the linq query code? Inside a method? Inside a property?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, that is the entirety of the class. Nothing more.

Comment: `User returnedUser = (from u in con.Users where u.username == user.username && u.password == user.password select u).First();`. You should be using `&&` instead of `and`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I reproduced this in .net Fiddle, this should work fine:

```
User returnedUser = (from u in con.Users
                                where u.username == user.username && u.password == user.password
                                select u).First();
```

Instead of `and` we use `&&`

Comment: I've tried that, but without the First() method, and it didn't work. It's why I didn't see this solution. Thank you though, it solved my problem.

Comment: @Compilerv2 as a side note, you should never store passwords plaintext in the db. Hash them with Salt and IV and store Hash, Salt and IV (but not the algorithm name).

Comment: Meh, I am doing this as an assignment for College, the professor won't try to hack my app ;).